# Corduroy etymology

Tags: etymology, eggcorn

The typical treatment of the etymology of "corduroy" notes that an oft-proposed explanation, French *cordes du roi*, "the king's ropes", is apocryphal, and that the word's origin is really unknown.

Looking at the French term for corduroy, *velour côtelé*, "ribbed velour", I wonder why I have seen no one remark on the similarity of "corduroy" to "côtelé", whether to acknowledge *or* discard it as an explanation. Even if it seems a bit of a stretch, they seem close enough to me to have at least evoked the possibility of a connection, perhaps *through* a "cordes du roi" [eggcorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn) analysis. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Apart from the fact that both have three syllables and begin in _co-_, I don’t really see any resemblance at all between the two.

Comment: Followed by a dental followed by a liquid.

Comment: Re the liquids, check out "colonel" and its pronunciation, or the relation among "pilgrim"/"peregrine"/French "pèlerin".

Comment: One followed by a liquid, then a voiced dental, then a front vowel, then a liquid, then a back-front diphthong; the other by an unvoiced dental, then a back vowel, then a (different) liquid, then a front vowel. Sure, they have a few common denominators, but not in any way that would make one likely to turn into the other. L and r are not generally confused in English, nor are e and oy. And d/t vacillation is unusual too. Altogether quite unlikely overall.

Comment: The difference between those and this one is that whose are both similations (two liquids dissimilated or assimilated), and that the process took place long ago, in Romance/early French. _Côtelé_ doesn’t have a second liquid to dissimilate from or assimilate to, and the process would have had to happen later on, within English, which is much rarer than it was in Romance.

Comment: I am a native French speaker (Canadian French, which is actually closer to old French than the French spoken in France today), and we still use the term "corduroy", and we pronounce it exactly like how our own ancestors would have pronounced "cordes du roi". Meaning the King's vestments. As for where it came from I have to believe some King wore it first somewhere and the term stuck around. Talk about making a fashion statement!

Comment: @DrunkenCodeMonkey: But was *corduroy* used in French before the word first appeared in English? The OED seems to say "no". So it looks like you borrowed *corduroy* from English, but it's quite possible the English borrowed the *du roi* part from French earlier.

Comment: Well, I'll be... There is actually a paper I found here: http://www.academia.edu/26253226/The_Etymology_of_Corduroy_A_Variation_on_Folk_Etymology that suggests a heavily ribbed "linon" (in French, linen) was imported into England from France as "corde rayée" (striped linen), but then English misunderstood "rayée" for "royal", and an Englishman (Chadwick) subsequently patented the linen in England as "Corduroy" in 1776, from a translation error (or smart marketing!).

Comment: ***rayée*** might have been confused with ***real*** (Spanish / Portuguese for *royal*)?

Comment: So probably what happened was that Chadwick thought *corde du roi* was a great name for a fabric, especially one with prominent ribs, and he anglicized it.  Much less interesting than all these incorrect etymologies, unfortunately.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquetjanus In U.S. English, at least, we have a complete merger of /d/ and /t/ in certain positions, such as in "utter"/"udder" and "metal"/"medal", so where would you get the idea this is unusual?

Answer (score 6):

According to the following [source](https://wordhistories.net/2016/08/16/corduroy/) the often suggested origins of the term like French “cordes du roi” or the English surname “Curdroy” appear to be folk etymologies. A more convincing  theory, though not definitive,  is the one  from “colour de roi”:

> The British philologist Ernest Weekley (1865-1954) proposed the most convincing origin in ***Transactions of the Philological Society (1910)***:
>
> - *Is there not a possibility that corduroy is folk-etymology for the common trade-term colour de roy?*
>
> ***The term colour de roy, which dates from the early 16th century, is from French couleur de roi, king’s colour.***  It originally denoted a cloth of a rich purple colour associated with the French kings and this colour itself. Later, it also signified a bright tawny colour and a cloth of this colour.
>
> ***[Ernest Weekley](https://books.google.it/books?id=TNxiHDi51n8C&pg=RA1-PA361&lpg=RA1-PA361&dq=corduroy%20etymology&source=bl&ots=OR-pJWYxRz&sig=JBZ4FLGJqHkXJcsSIssw7rWi0b4&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi67P26lbneAhXIxYUKHSjcCrY4HhDoATADegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=corduroy%20etymology&f=false) mentions that colour de roy occurs frequently in the scholarly editions of primary records of voyages, travels and other geographical material published by the Hakluyt Society.***  For example, in his diary, Richard Cocks (1566-1624), a merchant venturer living in Japan, wrote, on 26th November 1615:
>
> - *The king sent for a bottell Spanish wyne, and desird to buy Mr. Osterwickes cloake, being of culler du roy, which he sent unto hym at price of 20 taies.*
>
> (Incidentally, Richard Cocks was one of the first known users of the expression Hobson’s choice.)
>
> Ernest Weekley also cites Randle Cotgrave in A Dictionarie of the French and English Tongues (1611):
>
> - *Couleur de Roy, was in old time, Purple; but now is the bright Tawnie, which wee also tearme, Colour de Roy.*
>
> And Weekley concludes:
>
> - *The ‘bright tawnie’ is the commonest colour for new corduroys, and I imagine it might have been written commercially cᵒʳ de roy. This is, of course, a pure guess.*

(Word Histories)

Answer (score 6):

To support your speculation, there is the word *duroy*, pronounced /dəˈrɔɪ/. which was a kind of woolen cloth. The OED mentions this in the etymology section of *corduroy*, but says it "appears to have no connection to corduroy". However, this might explain why *côtelé* mutated to *cor duroy.* This would be especially likely if this mutation took place in a dialect where people dropped their *r*'s, which they seem to have done in London in the late 18th century.

The OED attests the word *duroy* meaning some kind of fabric from 1722:

> London Gazette (1722): Wearing a grey Duroy Coat and Wastcoat.

They also give a 1619 citation, but in that *deroy* seems to be a color (see the other answer).

The OED's definition of *duroy* is:

> A kind of coarse woollen fabric formerly manufactured in the west of England; akin to the stuffs called *tammies.* (Not the same as *corduroy.*)

And *duroy* does seem like it came from French. The OED gives a quote from a French encyclopedia

> *Encyclopédie Méthodique* (1792): *Duroi,* étoffe de laine, rase et sèche, dans le genre de la tamise, mais moins large et plus serrée,

which I'm not going to try to translate because these adjectives describing cloth in the 18th century probably don't mean quite the same thing as the same adjectives would in French today.

Comment: For the last part, first we need to know what Tamise is: http://www.atelierdudecorateur.com/public/img/big/tamise%20tissus%20decorateur%20tapissier.jpg . It's another type of woolen cloth, and the phrase describes Duroy as being flat and "dry" (as in not textured, smooth), like Tamise (previous link) but tighter. Not at all like corduroy...